# CollectionFactory Undefined type, inside DataProvider.php

Tags: magento2, uicomponent, data-provider

Whenever I try to use the CollectionFactory it appears as an error saying "undefidy type", what is happening? follow the code example

```
<?php


namespace Basic\Info\Model;

use Basic\Info\Model\ResourceModel\Blog\CollectionFactory;

class DataProvider extends \Magento\Ui\DataProvider\AbstractDataProvider
{
    /**
     * @var array
     */
    protected $loadedData;

    public function __construct(
        $name,
        $primaryFieldName,
        $requestFieldName,
        CollectionFactory $blogCollectionFactory,
        array $meta = [],
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->collection = $blogCollectionFactory->create();
        parent::__construct($name, $primaryFieldName, $requestFieldName, $meta, $data);
    }
    public function getData()
    {
        if (isset($this->loadedData)) {
            return $this->loadedData;
        }
        $items = $this->collection->getItems();
        foreach ($items as $blog) {
            $this->loadedData[$blog->getId()] = $blog->getData();
        }
        return $this->loadedData;
    }
}
```

what I get:

```
'Basic\Info\Model\ResourceModel\Blog\CollectionFactory'
```

Comment: Share the code of this file : Basic\Info\Model\ResourceModel\Blog\Collection

Comment: thank you already solved the problem, or better, there was no problem it was my IDE that alerted a false error, and I had not tried to compile the code to know if it would work.